# Bash Scripts - how to monitor CPU usage, so utilisation of idle time can be gained

Tags: bash, scripting, cpu-usage

I'm fairly new to shell scripting, but I'm trying to construct a simple script which will allow me to actively monitor the CPU usage (NOT LOAD), so that I may utilize the CPU idle time by running a process to keep it busy (any simple process as long as it keeps the CPU busy).

I've looked at many examples online, but can't seem to find anything that is of use -- so far all I've managed to do is find scripts that print the usage percentage, however I'd like to have a simple script where if the CPU usage is idle, it should do something... and if it is busy it should stop.

I'd really appreciate some help on the matter, guys.  Thanks.

Comment: The CPU will never be idle when the script checks, because the script is using the CPU.

Comment: Just run a process that contains an infinite loop continuously in the background, with low priority. It will keep the CPU busy, but not prevent other processes from running.

Comment: A shell script is the wrong tool for this; the CPU state will change from microsecond to microsecond, so even if the script didn't disrupt its own measurement (as @Barmar said) it'd still be too slow to react to be useful. Just run a low-priority process, and let the kernel figure out when to run it; that's the kernel's job. Also, why are you trying to do this? The only reasons I can think of are that you want to run up your power bill and/or stress-test your CPU's cooling system.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I'm doing this as project for my studies, I will also be using CRIU for this script, but that'll be later on, for now I would like the first part of the script to be constructed but im still not sure on how to go about this, could you guys leave me some examples on how i could achieve this as I'm quite new to using shell scripts.